# ng2-ckeditor How to set focus to the editor, when the editor is NOT auto-loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

I am using the ng2-ckeditor plugin. Using the documented way to set the focus (ie [on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944198/ckeditor-autofocus-on-the-text-editor-onload)) does not work, since I am using *ngIf to show the editor when the user clicks a button.

```
this.ckConfig = {
  uiColor: '#F0F3F4',
  height: '350',
  extraPlugins: 'divarea',
  startupFocus: true
};
```

So the startupFocus config option does not work, obviously, since the ckeditor is not actually in the DOM at this point.

I also tried using [hidden] since then the editor is in the DOM when my Component initializes, but of course the editor is not visible so it cannot receive focus anyway.

Then I discovered I can fire a ready event when the editor is actually visible and ready for user interaction, like so:

```
  <div *ngIf="isEditMode">
    <ckeditor id="ckeditor"
      [(ngModel)]="letterhead"
      [config]="ckConfig"
      (ready)="onReady($event)"
      debounce="500">
    </ckeditor>
  </div>
```

but how, in the OnReady event, can I set the focus?

**EDIT**

After digging into the innards of CKEditor, I found I can simply do this in my onReady event handler:

```
  onReady(event: any){
    event.editor.focus();
  }
```

This worked the first time I tried it. Now since I've reloaded the app it no longer works...wth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for some:

```
  onReady(event: any){
    event.editor.focus();
  }
```

but it takes the editor about 500-1000s milliseconds to load. So wrap the focus call in a timer:

```
  onReady(event: any){
    setTimeout(() => event.editor.focus(), 1000);
  }
```

However, in my situation the user can show or hide the editor by clicking a button. Since the onReady event then only fires when the DOM is actually ready (since it is part of the config options), it only fires once.

Therefore a more creative solution is needed.

First, I created a private variable in my component to store a ref to the editor:

private ckEditor: any;

then, when the onReady fires the first time, I store the reference to the ckEditor instance:

```
  onReady(event: any){
    this.ckEditor = event.editor;
  }
```

Now, when my user clicks the button that shows the editor:

```
  onClickEditButton(){
    this.isEditMode = true;
    this.isShowEditButton = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.ckEditor.focus(), 250);   
  }
```

I can set the focus every time it is shown! Yay! :)

Note that the timer can be much quicker here because by the time the user can click my Edit button (which fires this method), the DOM is fully loaded (as is the ckeditor plugin).

Answer (score 1):

The above answer did not work for me. So I found [this thread](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/106). Short answer, use `$event.editing.view.focus()`.

Long answer, in my case, I needed to delay creating the editor element until the user clicks on the wrapping element (to improve performance). After the user clicked, the editor is then created (the user does not know that, he just clicks on an area that "looks" as if there is an editor).

So what you have to do in html is

```js
    <ckeditor
      [editor]="editor"
      (ready)="onEditorReady($event)"
      data=""
      name="text">
    </ckeditor>
```

And the code

```js
  onEditorReady($event: any) {
    $event.editing.view.focus();
  }
```

No need for timeout. Also note that we are not working with the `editor` instance but with the `$event` instance.

The `$event.editing.view` objects prototype is where the focus() function is. Its also an object you can look for anything advanced that you would need to do programatically. For example, you can do `$event.editing.view.destroy()`. This will destroy the ckeditor but will still create a regular old textarea element. Not sure yet where this can be useful but here it is.